# assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new to c programming. I'm learning pointers in c, i tested simple file operation. In order to overcome overwrite the values in txt file. I declare file globally and inside the method i initialize the local pointer address to  global pointer address. my intention is use the same memory location. By using the same memory location carry out the file operations . Please be kind enough to find my program below.

```
FILE *f;// global pointer.

void myTest(char* val) {
    //d is local pointer.
    FILE *d = fopen("file.txt", "w");
        f=&d;
    if (f == NULL)
    {
     printf("Error opening file!\n");
         exit(1);
    }
   // print the data
   fprintf(f, "%s\n",val);

}

int main(void) {

    myTest("test");
    fclose(f);
}
```

**warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             f=&d;
After i run the bin file i get the 
Segmentation fault (core dumped) Error.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d` is a `FILE *`, so `&d` is a `FILE **`.  That can't be assigned to `f` which is a `FILE *`.

What you want is `f=d`.  Or just get rid of `d` entirely:

```
f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
```

Comment: thank you so much. i understood. after correcting that one the warning is gone. But i have Segmentation fault (core dumped) Error. any idea ? thank you.

Comment: @waruniguna With the above correction along with `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` the code runs as expected.  Post the updated code in your question that core dumps (but leave the code that's currently there).